# Adding Google's reCAPTCHA a to a class-based view in Django

Tags: python, json, django, recaptcha

I want to add recaptcha for signup view in my Django app. This below uses decorators.py to achieve that. I have tried other tutorials for adding reCAPTCHA also but does not seem working. Any idea why?

views.py

```
class signup_view(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'users/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.recaptcha_is_valid:
            form.save()
            return render(self.request, 'users/login.html', self.get_context_data())
        return render(self.request, 'users/signup.html', self.get_context_data())
```

urls.py

```
path("signup", check_recaptcha(signup_view.as_view()), name="signup"),
```

decorators.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
 
import requests
 
def check_recaptcha(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            data = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
            result = r.json()
            if result['success']:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            else:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = False
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
 
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

signup.html

```
    <div class="form">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <br>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfzEg8gAAAAABcVpBvOjuLjs787K8_4Fu0N2wgu"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use django-recaptcha? https://github.com/torchbox/django-recaptcha, basically you have to add a field in the form and add private and public key in the field, those should sit in local_settings or env file

Comment: actually, I have tried django-recaptcha however it didnt seem to work for form that uses (UserCreationForm) but only for (forms.Form) I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your decorator to:

```
def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
   request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
```

```
def wrap(obj, *args, **kwargs):
  request = obj.request
  request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
  ....
  return function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

so it can works with django views.

In view put it before form_valid:

```
@check_recaptcha
def form_valid(self, form):
```